# Is it possible to use a RadioButtonList with QueryExtender?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Is it possible to have a QueryExtender use a value from a RadioButtonList to filter results? Here is my current code:

```
<asp:QueryExtender ID="QueryExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="EntityDataSource1">
    <asp:PropertyExpression>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="rblFilter" Name="business_done" />
    </asp:PropertyExpression>
</asp:QueryExtender>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblFilter" runat="server" 
    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" DataValueField="" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>All</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

The underlying data field is a bit value, and I understand that Entity Framework interprets this as boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy .. [Here's a very nice article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203217/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081110-1.aspx) that teach you how to achieve this in both C# and VB.NET

> "ControlFilterExpression - used to
>   filter a field based on the value of a
>   particular Web control on the page
>   (such as a TextBox or DropDownList)."